# CodeFramework and method group. what does execute: Login mean?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm following [this CodeFramework example](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=1201061&page=2) and created a test project after installed Code Framework extension.

However, I'm not quite understand what this line of code mean in the LoginViewModel.

```
Actions.Add(new ViewAction("Enter", execute: Login));
```

I don't understand what "execute: Login" mean. More specificity what does execute: mean? Can you create this type of command or it's pre-defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Actions.Add(new ViewAction("Enter", execute: Login));
```

The `execute: Login` part is simply a named argument. Login has to be a value (probably a  method) in the current scope and execute is the name of the parameter.